# How can I format string with thousands separator on Mac with the Python locale library?

Tags: python, locale

I'd like to format a number with `.` for thousands separator and `,` for decimal point. I know I could do that with a triple `replace` and the `{:,}` format.

Is there a cleaner way to do it with the standard library `locale`?

First I found that even today the Mac `de_DE` locale does not include the thousands separator and you need to use the trick

```
locale._override_localeconv["thousands_sep"] = "."
locale._override_localeconv["grouping"] = [3, 0]
```

But next I do not know how to get the desired result

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
locale._override_localeconv["thousands_sep"] = "."
locale._override_localeconv["grouping"] = [3, 0]

x=123456.789
# -> expected result "123.456,789"

"{:n}".format(x)
# "123457" : rounding and no grouping

locale.format_string('%f', x, grouping=True)
# "123.456,789000" : extra zeros

locale.format_string('%g', x, grouping=True)
# "123.457" : rounding

"{:,}".format(x)
# "123,456.789" : no locale
```

Is there any way I can use `locale` to get the result `"123.456,789"`?

Answer (score 0):

As the question indicated, locale formatting floats requires a specification of precision. One approach is to calculate the needed precision for each number. Something like:

```py
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8')
def format_number_locale(num):
    precision = len(str(num).split('.')[1]) if isinstance(num, float) else 0
    frmt = f'%.{precision}f'
    if not locale.localeconv()['thousands_sep']:
        sep = locale.localeconv()['thousands_sep'] if locale.localeconv()['thousands_sep'] else locale.localeconv()['mon_thousands_sep']
        locale._override_localeconv["thousands_sep"] = sep
        locale._override_localeconv["grouping"] = locale.localeconv()['mon_grouping']
    return locale.format_string(frmt, num, grouping=True)

print(format_number_locale(1234567.09821))
# 1.234.567,09821
print(format_number_locale(1234567.01))
# 1.234.567,01
print(format_number_locale(1234567))
# 1.234.567
```

Not all locales in systems using BSD libc, like macOS have grouping separators, but are likely to have grouping separators for currency. So we can leverage off the separators specified for currency.

But if your code needs to be able to handle multiple locales, it would be more robust and less error prone to use icu4c and PyICU instead of the locale module:

```py
from icu import Locale, NumberFormat
def format_number_icu(num, formatter):
    precision = len(str(num).split('.')[1]) if isinstance(num, float) else 0
    formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(precision)
    formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(precision)
    return formatter.format(num)

frm = NumberFormat.createInstance(Locale('de_DE'))
print(format_number_icu(1234567.09821, frm))
# 1.234.567,09821
print(format_number_icu(1234567.01, frm))
# 1.234.567,01
print(format_number_icu(1234567, frm))
# 1.234.567
```